# Greasemonkey - inputting message into textarea of message box in Google Voice

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, google-voice

I am trying to write a script that will send a text to a number with a message of my choosing, but I am stuck on this part.

I am able to pass a number into the Google Voice "To" field by doing the following:

```
document.getElementById("gc-quicksms-number").value = number;
```

but I am unable to pass a message into the "Message" field with this:

```
document.getElementById("gc-quicksms-text2").value = "Error detected";
```

The block of code in the source looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/2LrhLZXc

Thank you! Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `document.getElementById("gc-quicksms-text2").value = "Error detected";` works perfectly fine in Firefox.  There must be something else in the script.  Paste or link to its source code.

Comment: I only have these two lines in the script, and the first part works fine but not the second.

Comment: in a test script I mean, just these two lines, the To field is populated fine but not the Message

Answer (score 0):

Since it's Google, that page is probably heavily ajax based.  Which means that `gc-quicksms-text2` is not there right away.  The fact that it's "text2" suggests that these `<textarea>`s may not always have the same id; they may be auto numbered.

So try the following:

1. Install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), if you haven't already.
2. Load and run this script:

   ```
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name            _Google voice starter
   // @include         http://www.google.com/googlevoice/*
   // @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
   // ==/UserScript==

   unsafeWindow.console.clear();
   var report = unsafeWindow.console.info;
   report ('GM Script start');


   var timerHandle = setInterval (checkForSMS_Textboxes, 777);

   function checkForSMS_Textboxes () {
       var SMS_Textboxes   = $('textarea.gc-quicksms-text');
       var SMS_Textboxes   = $('textarea');

       var newTB_ids       = SMS_Textboxes.map ( function () {
                               var jThis   = $(this);
                               if (jThis.prop ('bFoundBefore') )
                                   return null;
                               else {
                                   jThis.prop ('bFoundBefore', true);
                                   jThis.text ('Can you see me?');
                                   return this.id ? this.id : 'null';
                               }
                           } ).get ().join (', ');

       if (newTB_ids)
           report ('Found new textarea(s): ', newTB_ids);
   }
   ```
3. The code should fill in the SMS boxes and report each new text area to the [Firebug console](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel).  What does the console report?